# Retrieving data from a many-to-many relationship in a recipes database

Tags: sql, database, winforms, ado.net

I am attempting to create a recipes database where a user can input ingredients and it will output a list of potential recipes. I have created three tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Ingredients] (
[Ingredient_ID] INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Name]          VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Ingredient_ID] ASC)
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[recipes] (
[Recipe_ID]        INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Name]             VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[Instructions]     TEXT         NULL,
[Preperation_Time] FLOAT (53)   NULL,
[Author]           VARCHAR (50) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK.recipes] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Recipe_ID] ASC)
);

 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RecipeIngredients] (
[Recipe_ID]     INT NOT NULL,
[Ingredient_ID] INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Recipe_ID] ASC, [Ingredient_ID] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_RecipeIngredients_To_Ingredients] FOREIGN KEY ([Ingredient_ID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Ingredients] ([Ingredient_ID]),
CONSTRAINT [FK_RecipeIngredients_To_Recipes] FOREIGN KEY ([Recipe_ID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[recipes] ([Recipe_ID])
);
```

I have populated all tables and I am now attempting to retrieve the recipes based on what the user has entered.

I have a created a test SQL statement to retrieve all recipes that contain 'Eggs' using:

```
string sqlString = "SELECT recipes.Name, Instructions, recipes.Preperation_Time, Author FROM RecipeIngredients" +
                           " INNER JOIN recipes ON recipes.Recipe_ID = RecipeIngredients.Recipe_ID" +
                           " INNER JOIN Ingredients ON Ingredients.Ingredient_ID = RecipeIngredients.Ingredient_ID" +
                           " WHERE ingredients.Name = 'Eggs'";
```

The data does not show up in my dataGridView, but I am unsure if it is because the statement is wrong or other factors.

Is the statement correct? I am unfamiliar with the INNER JOIN command.

I am also unsure how to design an Sql statement that can take a varying amount of ingredient names without creating an Sql statement for every possibility.

Thanks in advance, if you need me to expand on anything I have asked please ask.

Comment: You marked this with the C# tag.  Where's your code?

Comment: If you run your query inside Sql Server Management Studio, what is the result?

Comment: To search for "any" of a list of ingredients you can use `IN` as in: `WHERE ingredients.name IN ('Eggs', 'Flour', 'Sugar')`.

Comment: And, assuming SSMS returns a result, does the debugger? if calling ADO or SQL ExecuteNonQuery or whatever you are doing DOES return a List or Enumerable, where does it fail when you debug?

Comment: The query is correct, so, if you don't see any result we have two possibilities. 1) There is no recipe that use the ingredient 'Eggs' and we cannot see your db. 2) There is an error in your code and you have not posted your code. This is the situation that leads to closing a question because it lacks a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the query that should work. Use of aliases is recommended

```
SELECT r.Name, r.Instructions, r.Preperation_Time, r.Author 
FROM Ingredients i 
join RecipeIngredients ri on i.Ingredient_ID = ri.Ingredient_ID
join recipes r on ri.Recipe_ID = r.Recipe_ID
where i.Name = 'Eggs'
```

You may want to run it through SQL Server Management Studio to ascertain return of result before coding it in C# solution.